# excel value of third cell based on value of first and variable cell numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm struggling to get the value of a cell, here is what i need to find: value of

```
 $table1.$Bx IF $table1.$Ax = $table2.$G28
```

x is variable based on the value of G28

e.g if G28 = 1 then it would need the content of 
     B1 IF A1 = G28

FYI: Bx is numeric, Cx is text, G28 is numeric, I don't know if that would affect the composition of the formula.
How would i write the cell variable? $table1.$B% ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the volatile¹ [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) to construct a valid cell address from quoted strings and values contained in other cells.

```
=IF(INDIRECT("'Sheet1 One'!A"&$G28) = $G28, INDIRECT("'Sheet1 One'!B"&$G28), "")
```

It is unnecessary to use the absolute **$** anchor within the quoted string. Text that looks like a cell address will not change when copied or filled to a new location. Conversely, the **$** is necessary in **$G28** if the formula is to be filled right and the **G** should not change.

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>